# How can I add sku to dropdown?

Tags: magento2.3.1

In this function-

```
 public function getResults()
{
    $results = [];
    foreach ($this->getLoadedProductCollection() as $product) {
        $data['img'] = $this->encodeMediaUrl(
            $this->getImage($product, 'amasty_xsearch_page_list')- 
>toHtml()
        );
        $data['url'] = $product->getProductUrl();
        $data['name'] = $this->getName($product);
        $data['description'] = $this->getDescription($product);
        $data['sku'] = $this->getSku($product);
        $data['price'] = $this->getProductPrice($product);
        $data['is_salable'] = $product->isSaleable();
        $data['product_data'] = [
            'entity_id' => (string)$product->getId(),
            'request_path' => (string)$product->getRequestPath()
            ];
        $data['reviews'] = $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($product, 
   ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW);
        $results[$product->getId()] = $data;
    }

    $this->setNumResults($this->getLoadedProductCollection()- 
>getSize());
    return $results;
        }
```

I added this line-

```
$data['sku'] = $this->getSku($product);
```

I then created this function-

```
public function getSku(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    return $this->getResults()->get($sku);
}
```

On the page I am trying to display it on I have this code-

```
 <?= $product['sku'] ?>
```

The extension pulls the name and description so I tried to just copy what was done for those attributes but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: your getSku function should recieved a `$sku` variable `public function getSku($sku)
{
    return $this->getResults()->get($sku);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems as it infinity call stack, can you edit your added line to

```
$data['sku'] = $product->getSku();
```

or edit your function to

```
public function getSku(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
   return $product->getSku();
}
```

Comment: I changed the function and that worked great, but I don't understand why. Could you explain a little if you get a chance? If not I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @TylerJensen inner function `getResult` you call `getSku` then inside `getSku` call `getResult`, it is a infinity stack trace.

Comment: That makes sense thanks you.